# Which one of these two fields results in faster database query?

Tags: mysql, database, performance

My database uses MySQL with InnoDB engine. Fields in the user table:

**user_id** - primary key, long type
**nickname** - unique, varchar under 20 characters, could be indexed if needed

and other not relevant fields.

Now, which one will be faster assuming user has 500 000 records? Finding user by user_id or nickname?

Comment: Comparing numbers is always faster than comparing strings of characters, so probably finding by user_id would be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I'd do the test myself but I don't have the necessary needs right now.

Comment: If InnoDB is in question, *the fastest* way possible is using an auto incrementing integer for PK (for looking up records based on that number). Reason for this is InnoDB's clustering approach and all the nice optimizations that come with it. You can research this by googling if you will, but short answer is what I mentioned.

Comment: I was thinking about switching to Integer type instead of Long because I've read a comment somewhere saying that Long type performs very poorly in InnoDB MySQL. I'll do some additional research but I think I might end up just changing it to Integer. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some testing on a table with 100k rows, searching by primary key is indeed slightly faster, just as **N.B.** mentioned. The difference however is barely noticable as it's usually just few ms. This might get higher with larger tables though.
Moreover, after using Explain query, key_length is obviously few times shorter in numeric values such as int/long than string. This probably won't make any difference in performance but it's still worth mentioning.
So yeah, I'll stick to searching by id whenever possible. Thanks for your comments.